# Calling different POST variables using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm still new to jQuery and stuck trying to figure this one out, hope someone can help. I have this jQuery code that needs to pass different values depending on the clicked element. Each element created has a unique number in it's ID (which is needed). If I manually change the jQuery code to a specific ID and call, for example:

```
http://mysite/examplepost?effect=113
```

This will work. But I need to have $('#div- ...different numbers here...') to be able to handle multiple elements on the same page. I already have the PHP side producing different values using:

```
if($_GET['effect'] == $id){
```

I just need this to work with ajax so that it doesn't reload the page.

Example:

```
$('#div-113').on('click', function() {

    var dataString = 'effect=113';  

        jQuery.ajax(
            {
            type:'GET',
            url:'?',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                alert('Works');         
            }
          }
        );

      });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give all your `div`s a common classname (i.e. `myClickableDiv`) and also a specific `data-id`.

This way you can target all your divs by that common classname, rather than having to figure it out depending on how the `id` is formed.  The `data-id` allows you to only provide very specific information to the click handler (like an integer), without having to parse the `id`.

HTML:

```
<div class=".myClickableDiv" id="div-XXX" data-id="XXX">My Div</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.myClickableDiv').on('click', function() {

    var dataString = $(this).attr('data-id');  

    jQuery.ajax({...});

});
```